# Can you explain me callfun.counter is a local or global variable ???? #If local what scope of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, global, local

```
def callfun():
    callfun.counter += 1
callfun.counter = 0

for i in range(10):
    callfun()
    print(callfun.counter)
```

I'm unable to under callfun.counter is a local or global variable. #NewProgrammer

Output:

> 123...10

Comment: It's not a variable at all, it's a property of the `callfun` (function) object

Comment: In fact, it is a variable, also a local attribute of the function named callfun.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a variable. And you are using it as an object (callfun.counter) and as a function (callfun()). I suppose you don't want to have it named the same.